# Should articles be used before adjective after "or"?

Tags: articles

Should both the articles be used here? Or one? Or none?

> 1) You are using **an** invalid or **an** expired link.
>   2) I need **a** small or **a** medium-size box, not large.
>   3) Please take **a** green or **a** blue piece of paper. 
>   4) There are 3 pencils of 3 colors. Please take **the** red or **the** blue one.

Answer (score 1):

The first article is needed; the second is not wrong, but not needed either.  Unless it adds clarity (not the case for any of your examples here), it's better to omit it.

Comment: Thank you. How about "I need either a small or a medium-size box, not both." ?